# Move constructor not called

Tags: c++, c++11, move, copy-constructor, move-semantics

After trying to write an example regarding move constructors, I ran into the following code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Data
{
public:
    Data()
    : x (3)
    {
        cout << "Data()" << endl;
    }
    Data(Data&&)
    : x(4)
    {
        cout << "Data(&&)" << endl;
    }

int x;
};

int main()
{
    Data a;
    Data b (std::move(a));
    cout << b.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the move constructor not called here?
The program prints:

> Data()
>
> 3

What I'm finding even weirder is that by adding a copy constructor, suddenly, it does call the move constructor...

```
    Data(const Data&)
    : x(2)
    {
        cout << "Data(copy)" << endl;
    }
```

And now it will print

> Data(&&)
>
> 4

P.S I'm using gcc 4.4.5

Comment: Strange... I'm under ubuntu, GCC 4.8. It calls the move constructor.
What compiler are you using?

Comment: Same here (move constructor is called properly), with gcc 4.7.2.

Comment: It [does](https://ideone.com/CS5LC3) get called. What's your compiler and which version?

Comment: I suspect it is a microsoft compiler, is it?

Comment: @GreenScape I don't think so, VC11 behaves properly in this case.

Comment: This question looks bogus. The purported output cannot be the actual output: There are no blank lines generated by the code, and the second output block is missing the output from the default constructor, which would surely be there. It looks too much like a hand-typed copy of something half-remembered than actual output for this to allow a meaningful analysis.

Comment: compiling using gcc 4.4.5, after seeing these comments i suspect it's a bug under this specific version

Comment: @KerrekSB, You are correct, it is manually copied from another computer which is not connected to the internet, but this is the actual code, I can't find any differences.

Comment: gcc 4.4.5 was released in October 2010, well before the final version of the C++11 specification. I wouldn't expect it to be completely conforming.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, your code works properly for me. [See this sample](https://ideone.com/VkYe0U).

Output:

```
Data()
Data(&&)
4
```

As standard says:

> The move constructor is called whenever an object is initialized from
>   **xvalue** of the same type, which includes
>
> - initialization, `T a = std::move(b);` or `T a(std::move(b));`, where `b` is of type `T`
> - function argument passing: `f(std::move(a));`, where a is of type `T` and `f` is `void f(T t)`
> - function return: `return a;` inside a function such as `T f()`, where a is of type T which has a move constructor.

And

> `std::move` obtains an rvalue reference to its argument and converts it to an **xvalue**.

I see no reason for behavior you describe. Perhaps there is something wrong with your compiler?

---

**EDIT**

It seems, that it is indeed the fault of the compiler. Definition of move functions was described in proposal [N3053](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3053.html) ("Defining Move Special Member Functions"). As we can see in table on [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your code is well-formed and should call the move constructor. However, gcc 4.4, does not support defining move functions as stated [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

You do want to consider to update your compiler.